# merge the result of map in one array

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
const data = {
  data: [
    {
      entry: [
        {
          id: 1,
          title: "hello",
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          title: "hi",
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      entry: [
        {
          id: 3,
          title: "hola",
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          title: "hey",
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
};
let rec = data.data.map((d) => {
  return d.entry.map((reco) => {
    return console.log(reco);
  });
});
```

how can I merge the extract data from mapping function into one array like this?

I tried reduce function and flat function but it doesn't work

```
[{id:1 ,  title: "hello"} ,{id:2 , title: "hi"} , {id:3 , title: "hola"} ,{id:4 , title: "hey"} ]
```

I edit it with better and complete example

Comment: Is `recArray` array a 2d array? Its a bit hard to tell from your example where `[{id:3 , name:"v"} ,{id:4 , name:"p"}]` sits

Comment: What does the `.reduce()` result produce and what's not working with it? Please use [stack snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to create a runnable example of your issue so we can help you better.

Comment: You can use `flatMap` for this

Comment: I create a runnable example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) method to flatten a multidimensional array while mapping it.

```
const data = {
  data: [
    {
      entry: [
        {
          id: 1,
          title: "hello",
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          title: "hi",
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      entry: [
        {
          id: 3,
          title: "hola",
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          title: "hey",
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
}
const flat = data.data.flatMap(item => item.entry)
```

Comment: Just a heads up - OP has edited the question, with a different object structure.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use map to iterate over each item and return the entry array

Then use flat to merge these arrays into a single array like this:

```
let rec = data.data.map(d => d.entry).flat();
```